# sheet.getCharts() not returning EmbeddedCharts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When using the [getCharts() method of a Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()) instance, no charts are returned. This seems to be caused by the chart being a combo chart (rather than a more basic column, bar or pie chart). I modified the chart to be a column chart and [getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()) worked...returning a chart.

I can't find any confirmation that combo charts are completely ignored by the Spreadsheet App Script API.

Does anyone know of any SO questions, forum posts or official documentation that clarifies support (or lack thereof) for combo charts?

While there is [no ComboChartBuilder for the Sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), I was hoping for something a little more explicit than the absence of a ComboChartBuilder. I would have thought [getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()) should return a Chart even if it's not modifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to get a chart that isnt possible to build with apps script. You already found out the 'builder' class is missing.
There isnt a list of the unsupported ones, just the list of charts you can build with gas which are the sames you can get.